# Log4Net RollingFileAppender Can't Delete Files as Network Service

Tags: c#, iis, log4net

I have log4net creating a log and debug file daily on a Windows 2008 server as part of an ASP.MVC application that runs as Network Service. It creates the logs fine but there is also a clean up operation that runs but this is having a permission problem deleting the file. I get the error that:

```
Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\Testing\MyApplication\log\Error-2016.08.22.log' is denied.
```

If I change the permissions on the file so that Network Service has complete control then the application can delete it fine.

Here's the code:

```
    private void ConfigLog4Net(int maxAgeInDays)
    {
        var sFilename = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\Log4Net.config";
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(
            new System.IO.FileInfo(sFilename));

        Log.InfoFormat("Log4Net Config - {0}", sFilename);

        var repository = LogManager.GetRepository() as Hierarchy;
        if (repository != null)
        {
            var appenders = repository.GetAppenders();
            if (appenders != null)
            {
                foreach (var appender in appenders)
                {
                    if (appender is RollingFileAppender)
                    {
                        var rollingFileAppender = appender as RollingFileAppender;
                        CleanupLogs(rollingFileAppender, maxAgeInDays);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private void CleanupLogs(RollingFileAppender appender, int maxAgeInDays)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(appender.File)) return;
        var datePatternBits = appender.DatePattern.Split(new char[]{'\''}, StringSplitOptions.None);
        if (datePatternBits.Count() != 5 || datePatternBits[0].Length > 0 || datePatternBits[4].Length > 0)
            throw new ApplicationException(
                string.Format(
                    "Log4Net RollingFileAppender ({0} DatePattern unexpected format. Expected \"\'xxx\'date\'eee\'\" {1},{2},{3}",
                    appender.Name, datePatternBits.Count(), datePatternBits[0].Length, datePatternBits[4].Length));
        List<string> logPatternsToKeep = new List<string>();
        for (var i = 0; i <= maxAgeInDays; i++)
            logPatternsToKeep.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-i).ToString(appender.DatePattern));

        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(appender.File);

        var searchString = string.Format("{0}*{1}", datePatternBits[1], datePatternBits[3]);
        var folderFiles =
            fileInfo.Directory.GetFiles(searchString);
        var logFiles = folderFiles
            .Where(x => logPatternsToKeep.All(y => !x.Name.Contains(y) && x.Name != fileInfo.Name));

        foreach (var log in logFiles)
            if (File.Exists(log.FullName)) File.Delete(log.FullName);
    }
```

Is there something I need to do to Network Service permissions or do I need to change the code so that it automatically allows Network Service to delete the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Network Service doesn't have permissions to delete files in the log directory.

You need to give Network Service permission to delete files in the C:\inetpub\Testing\MyApplication\log\ directory (not the files in it but the directory itself).